# Merging multiple vector layers to one layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, merge

I've imported several shapefiles which where exported from a Mapinfo `.tab`. Several  `.tab`-files are imported resulting in 20+ layers.

Afterwards I want to export it to GeoJSON; but I'm reluctant to select each layer and export it manually.

Is there a way to merge all the layers into one using QGIS?

Comment: All these functions can be accessed via the Sextante plugin, also in Lisboa

Comment: yes, the tools works perfectly. Just if the input shapefiles are in UTF8, the output shapefile lose atributes.... is there any way to say QGIS to create SHP in UTF8 ? something like in ArcGIS, where you can in registry set the value defaul codepage to UTF8?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) tools for merging...

[image: mmqgis]

> The merge layers tool merges features from multiple layers into a
> single shapefile and adds the merged shapefile to the project. One or
> more layers are selected from the "Select Source Layers" dialog list
> box and an output shapefile name is specified in the "Output
> Shapefile" dialog field.
>
> Merged layers must all be the same geometry type (point, polygon,
> etc.). If the source layers have different attribute fields
> (distinguished by name and type), the merged file will contain a set
> of all different fields from the source layers with NULL values
> inserted when a source layer does not have a specific output field.

Comment: There is such an option, under the vector menu, data management tool

Comment: what about if the two or more layers have different coordinate systems?? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279571/mmqgis-merge-layers-that-have-different-coordinate-systems

Comment: One benefit of the MMQGIS merge tool is that it can handle attribute fields with the same name but different types - the builtin merge layer tool throws an error when this happens.

Comment: MMQGIS cuts the column characters in the data attribute table to just 10. See my answer below.

Answer (score 94):

You can use the 'merge shapefiles to one' function under the menu vector|Data management tool. You can merge all files in the input directory or select specific files in the input directory.

[image]

The same applies as for MMqgis tool: merged layers must all be of the same geometry type. Also, if the source layers have different attributes fields, the merged file will contain all fields, but with NULL values inserted when a source layer does not have a specific field.

Answer (score 15):

In the meantime, a tool called ["Merge vector layers"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers) has been added to QGIS under `Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Vector Layers` or under `Vector general` in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

[image: merge vector layers screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the [`v.patch`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.patch.html) module under GRASS GIS commands. It's available in the processing toolbox.

You can search for it when the dropdown at the bottom of the Processing Toolbox window is switched from *"Simplified interface"* to *"Advanced interface"*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the **Vector - Data Management Tools -> Merge Vector Layers** instead of MMQGIS -> Combine -> Merge Layers.

The reason behind is is your data attribute table. MMQGIS reduces the characters limit to 10, unlike the Merge Vector Layers tool. You can still use it, although be aware that your naming will be cut, as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you please tell us how your answer differs from @stopopol's answer?

Comment: It shows clearly which option we should use. I've marked in red the streaking difference between the MMQGIS merge layers and Merge Vector Layers. MMQGIS cuts column names at the same basis as shapefile does.

Comment: I would suggest extending the answer from @stopopol's instead of putting it as a separate answer. why? because your answer wraps in end effect the **"Merge Vector Layers"** which was already mentioned.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. My answer basically combines both @stopopol and Aragon answer. Just noticed the difference between the two and decided to forewarn everyone, who has the data attribute columns longer than 10 characters.