# How to merge way points from many GPX files?

Tags: qgis, merge, gpx

I have a large number of Waypoint-layers (gpx) and would like to merge them.

Is there a way to do so using QGIS?

Comment: Do you want to merge as in "The target layer should contain all points of all source layers combined, even if some of them are at the same location"?
Also, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/how-to-merge-multiple-layers-to-one-layer .

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste works with almost every layer.

I would suggest to create a new point shapefile, change it to edit mode, select the waypoints layer by layer with rectangle , and paste them into the shapefile layer.

---

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can use the mmqgis plugin, `Transfer -> merge layers`