# Creating points where lines intersect in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, intersection

I have two line layers, and I want to create a point where they cross each other.

How can I solve it in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on this answer [How to identify line intersection in QGIS when I have more than 2 lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86308/how-to-identify-line-intersection-in-qgis-when-i-have-more-than-2-lines) you can use the built in tool [Line Intersections](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#line-intersections).

Add both line layers to your canvas then from the vector menu select analysis tools then line intersections. Populate the two line layers and the output and hit ok.

[image]

*Note* this tool will not flag self-intersections (where a line crosses itself). The documentation on this tool is very sketchy and a little hard to find but I think it will do what you're after.