# How to union linestring data distributed on multiple layers?

Tags: qgis, merge, dissolve, union

I have four shapefiles. Each contains a linestring as shown in the image. Each shapefile is represented as its own layer in QGIS.

[image: Four linestrings]

I would like to union these linestrings into one polygon which describes the outline of all four shapes as shown in the following image I produced with Gimp. I could not [dissolve the parts](http://www.studytrails.com/blog/merge-shapefile-polygons-using-quantum-gis/) since they are spread on four layers.

[image: Outline]

I [uploaded the shapefiles](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2071482/Pfinztal-all.zip) for you to try yourself. The archive contains the four separate shapes as well as the merged geometries (*Pfinztal-Merged-4326.zip*) I produced.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/how-to-merge-multiple-layers-to-one-layer-using-qgis then dissolve using your instructions.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson The [MMQGIS plugin](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) works good. However, **non** of the layers has a attribute column which has a **common value** for all nodes. Therefore, I cannot dissolve the shapes by such a column.

Comment: Does that *really* matter? if you just want them dissolved add a field and set them all the same.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I already tried but could not find out how to **apply the same value to hundreds of rows** in the attribute editor (without [manually copy/pasting them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuuFEq0a5gg)).

Comment: http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html right click on layer, open attribute table and use field calculator.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson, you should post the steps as an answer. Easier for the OP to understand, plus the method you describe should be a solution for this problem.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Yes, please convert your comments into a full answer. Your steps should work - I will try them in a few hours.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I add a `xxx` column to each shapefile. All rows in this column have the same value for one shapefile. The values are `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` for all shapefiles. I successfully merged the shapefiles using MMQGIS. The merged shapefile took over the different values assigned before. When I dissolve by the `xxx` column all **inner lines stay**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To dissolve the interior lines they must have the same value. All the values of xxx should be the same for a proper dissolve. Is there any reason why the lines need to have different attributes? I was under the impression that you just wanted to dissolve the lines; the tool is doing what it's supposed to do keeping lines of different attributes, where there is a common line the attributes need to be the same to eliminate one of the lines. If you need different attributes then apply them after dissolving.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I am actually not interested in any of the attributes besides the geometry coordinates.

Comment: Set your XXX values all the same and dissolve, that should remove duplicate lines provided they are overlaid, if they are not perfect have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/removing-small-spaces-slivers-between-polygons to make the lines coalesce.

Comment: Strike. This time it worked. Important detail: The shapefiles **cannot be loaded from a .zip file** because the attributes table will not be writeable then. Further all linestrings of the outline must have an **equal value** in a temporary column - an the inner linestrings must have an **odd value**. - Michael, would you please sum up the steps in a full answer - then I am happy to grant you the answer flag. Thank you.