# How to combine a road network to multiple shapefiles with no shared attributes

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am trying to create an agent-based model and I need a .CSV file that contains the attributes of a routable road network and a number of other shapefiles I have.

I have the following:

- [Ordnance Survey Integrated Transport Network shapefile](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/itn-layer.html)
- [Office for National Statistics 2011 LSOA Boundaries shapefile](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/products/census/spatial/2011/index.html)
- [Office for National Statistics 2011 LSOA population-weighted Centroids shapefile](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/products/census/spatial/centroids/index.html)
- a self-made shapefile that contains half a dozen points that represent hospitals

**How, in QGIS, can I combine the attributes of all the above shapefiles?**

In my model, I need to be able to load the road network, then use a .CSV file to assign my agents certain 'home' locations (using info in the LSOA shapefile above), then have my agents use the road network to navigate to other certain points (LSOA Centroids or Hospitals).

The shapefiles do **NOT** have any shared attributes.

Answer (score 2):

In Arc this would be handled by the append tool with NO_TEST as an option.  In QGIS, and forgive me I am not as experienced in it, but I believe the MERGE tool is the equivalent.  Since the shapefiles do not have the same attributes all the attributes that are matching, and unmatching, will be pulled through to the newly merged shapefile. Now MERGE will only allow you to MERGE shapefiles of the same geometry type. But the way I read your question you really just need the ROAD NETWORK merged into one, and the points can still be in a seperate shapefile.  The actual routing I believe can be handled by the QGIS plugin, pgROUTING, where you can specify you network and your points and then voila it will spit out the best route.

[Merging multiple vector layers to one layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/how-to-merge-multiple-layers-to-one-layer-using-qgis)

http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/pgrouting/