# How to merge attribute table properties from one layer to another in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am using QGIS 2.2.3 (Lyon). I have a vector layer with a linked attribute table. In order to do multiple tests on the layer, i created a copy in a new layer. The attribute table on this new layer is empty. I want this new layer to have the same layout/properties than the original.

Is there a way to merge the layout from one layer to another ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the merge tool :

Vector -> Data Management tools -> merge shapefile to one, which will open up new window “Merge Shapefiles”,

Here is a tutorial on that method.

http://www.igismap.com/merge-two-shapefile-qgis/

[Merging multiple vector layers to one layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/how-to-merge-multiple-layers-to-one-layer-using-qgis)

ALternatively, why dont you just create an exact copy of your layer by clicking on the layer, and choosing save as, and saving the shapefile to a new location, then choose add the new layer to the map, then you can work on the new layer to run your tests.

** also when you say linked attribute table, do you mean they tables are joined, or related, or ??

Comment: What i meant is : « I have a vector layer with an associated attribute table ».          Thank you by the way :) !