# Merging overlapping polygons with SpatiaLite

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, spatialite, dissolve

The green points, buffered by one of the point attributes, should result in the three areas outlined in red (a table with three rows):

[image]

How can I do this with SpatiaLite?

If it's not possible, is there any other way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Should be doable with SQL inside Spatialite. Do you mean that the point table has a numeric attribute, let's call it "radius", and you would like to start by buffering `ST_Buffer(geometry, radius)`?

Comment: @user30184 yes, the buffer radius is based on a numeric value

Comment: For QGIS see this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/merging-multiple-vector-layers-to-one-layer-using-qgis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a step-wise process. Queries were made with Spatialite-gui and visualizations with OpenJUMP.

Take some points into table "points" with an attribute "radius".

[image]

Buffer points by taking the radius from an attribute with SQL

```
CREATE TABLE "buffers" AS
SELECT ST_Buffer("geometry", "radius") as geometry FROM points;
```

[image]

Union the buffer areas with SQL

```
CREATE TABLE "combined" AS
SELECT ST_Union(geometry) as geometry FROM buffers;
```

[image]

Union is one big multipolygon at this stage. Split it to three distinct geometries with SQL

```
SELECT ElementaryGeometries('combined', 'geometry', 'elements', 'ID', 'poly_ID');
```

Have a look at the new table "elements"

[image]

The result is close to your sketch, isn't it?

**Note**: You must execute some additional SQL statements or use the tools of the spatialite-gui besides the ones I have written for registering the geometry columns of the interim tables. I hope my answer is complete enough for a proof of concept.

You can write ST_Union and ST_Buffer into same SQL but it is necessary to create a physical table "combined" and register it into geometry_columns for making ElementaryGeometries function to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "registering the geometry columns of the interim tables"? Is that what is outlined here: http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html ? That would make sense to me because I can omit doing those those steps manually when I run an SQL query in QSpatialite and hit "Create spatial table and view in QGIS"

Comment: I mean the same thing. Current Spatialite version is 4.3 and version 4.4 is soon out but the old cookbook seems to be still usable. See AddGeometryColumn and RecoverGeometryColumn at https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html and compare with the cookbook. Spatialite-gui and Qspatialite have special tools for that purpose. If you create a new table with CREATE AS SELECT... it will be unusable for QGIS and ElementaryGeometries because they both want to check some metadata from the metadata tables.

Comment: st_union returned something that looked exactly like the original buffered points, unlike what you showed in your screenshot. The result of the call to `ElementaryGeometries` is empty (those observations might be related)

Comment: Hard to say why you are getting different result. What does your Spatialite return with this query that simulates your use case with simple overlapping rectangles: `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Union(ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON (( 320 320, 320 400, 380 400, 380 320, 320 320 ))'),ST_GeomFromText('
POLYGON (( 340 280, 340 360, 400 360, 400 280, 340 280 ))')))` I get `POLYGON (( 320 320, 320 400, 380 400, 380 360, 400 360, 400 280, 340 280, 340 320, 320 320 ))` from Spatialite and also from PostGIS with the same query.

Comment: that seems to work fine. After trying again from scratch I can also achieve the desired result with your instructionson my own data. Unfortunately, I have not been able to create a view-like thing out of these because `ElementaryGeometries`will always create a new table, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it creates a new table. I believe that a view will not work because the selected row with multipolygon will yield many rows after the split to elementary polygons. QGIS has tools for splitting and perhaps you can invent some own splitter that is using plain SQL. Spatialite has a function NumGeometries that returns the number of elementary geometries and function GeometryN which selects the n:th elementary geometry. Happy scripting with looping from 1 to n!

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS you'd use the merge shapefiles function, just be sure to choose the correct couples/triplets/whatever.
From the program menu, Vector -> Data management tools -> merge shapefiles

Answer (score 1):

You could to use Dissolve Tool

But, perhaps you could to create a buffer using the parameter:

Dissolve result=YES
[image]

Comment: I think this comes close to what I need and I'll try it. One drawback is that I need to actually create a field with the desired buffer radius, while a database query allows me to calculate it.

Comment: You could to create a view with a field with the desired buffer radius, and then you could to use "Variable distance Buffer" (SAGA): Input Layer= View from DB.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, it is an aggregation query. You can do something like:

```
Select st_Union(geom) from your_table group by the_attribute_which_make_each_group
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no attribute other than the buffered points' overlapping-ness, so at least one step is missing here. Creating a grouping attribute from the buffered points in the first place is something I can't come up with myself.

Comment: The "group by" could use the result of a spatial query. Check this: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ClusterIntersecting.html