# How to use ST_LineMerge or ST_Union to merge lines in QGIS virtual layers

Tags: qgis, postgis, virtual-layer

If have an input layer with a couple of lines, called `Line` with an attribute. I would like to have a virtual layer with alle connecting lines dissolved, regardless of the attribute.

input:

[image]

expected output as in "dissolve" with keep disjoint features separate

[image]

I used the following query:
`select ST_LineMerge(geometry) as geometry from Line`
But the connected lines are not merged:

[image]

Using `ST_Union` in the following query yields me a single multipart feature:
`select st_multi(st_union((geometry))) as geometry from Line`

[image]

could the `Group by`segment with something like `Disjoint` be an option? Like

```
select st_multi(st_union((geometry))) as geometry from Line
Group By disjoint
```

Comment: If you happen to have Postgis, it is much easier to do via a [spatial cluster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408695/compound-contiguous-links-to-lines-in-a-network-and-find-isolated-lines).

Comment: Hard, if not impossible, via a virtual layer. See this similar [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191970/merging-overlapping-polygons-with-spatialite). There is no clustering function to detect all touching geometries, and it is almost impossible to extract individual geometries from a multigeometry (still technically feasible, with the use of recursive functions... honestly, it's not worth the effort)

Comment: many thanks! But would the application of `ST_LineMerge(geometry)` be correct in this case?

Comment: It depends what you want to do... `st_lineMerge` requires a multiline and will try to stitch segments together. So maybe you could create one giant multiline, st_lineMerge it and explode it again (but not in a VL)

Comment: It depends of your geometries, they should merge with ST_LineMerge if they really touch, if they don't that means they don't really touch. You can fix them with functions like ST_SnapToGrid, or merge cluster of lines close enough with cluster done with ST_ClusterDBSCAN for example.