# Merging layers, then dissolving and keeping all attribute values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, merge

I have three layers in QGIS, each with one feature, including some attributes.

- **Layer 1** has attributes *a*, *b*, and *c*,
- **Layer 2** has attributes *d*, *e*, and *f* and
- **Layer 3** has attributes *g*, *h*, and *i*

I want to merge all three layers and keep all attribute values.

When I run "Dissolve", I get the values of attributes *a*, *b*, and *c*. The attributes from the other two layers are there, but with `NULL` values (the normal case after dissolve).

But what is the solution in QGIS to have one dissolved layer with one feature including all nine attributes with their respective values?

Comment: How I'd approch this: Union https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union to get all the attributes together, add a new field and calculate it by appending attributes a to i with a pipe or similar delimiter then dissolve by that attribute to find your unique polygons, use polygon centroids to extract the centroid points from the unmerged polygons then spatial join https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html the centroids to the merged polygons to retrieve your attributes.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/merging-multiple-vector-layers-to-one-layer-using-qgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a virtual layer with this query and export/save it to make it permanent:

```
select a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, 
st_union(layer1.geometry, st_union(layer2.geometry,layer3.geometry)) 
from layer1, layer2, layer3
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution from @Babel will result in only one feature with 9 columns, if you want to have 3 features with 3 columns and attributes you have to use a `union` instead:

```
select * from Layer1
union
select * from Layer2
union
select * from Layer3
```

Comment: I was looking for the solution as proposed by @Babel. But yours is a useful additional hint.